# C# - Trying to add a file path into NavigateUri which could be different for every user

Tags: c#, wpf-controls

I am trying to add a filepath hyperlink into my WPF project that has the potential for part of it to be different for every user. I know a registry location where I can get the first section of the path and the second section of the path will always be the same.

For example the path I am trying to get to (which works when coded in this manner) looks like this in my .xaml file:

```
<TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" FontSize="18"
           FontWeight="Bold" Margin="0,-35,140,0">
    <Hyperlink RequestNavigate="Hyperlink_RequestNavigate"
               NavigateUri="G:\Applications\SimHub\DashTemplates\OMSC - Settings\readme.pdf">Readme Link</Hyperlink>
</TextBlock>
```

The first section "G:\Applications\SimHub" is the part that has the potential to change and the second section "\DashTemplates\OMSC - Settings\readme.pdf" is the part that will always be the same.

I know of the registry functions and binding methods but I have no idea how to use them properly to get the result that I need.

What I need to do, ultimately, is I need a function to get me the 'variable' section of the path from the registry. Then the 'constant' section of the path needs to be added on the end (which the whole thing then needs to become a string I assume). I then need to bind that NavigateUri part in my .xaml to the resulting string that is created in the code.

Can someone please help? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a value converter. Here I bound the Navigate Uri to a custom converter that will look in the registry for the base path of an application and then append a path to some file.

```
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Data;

 namespace ApplicationHyperLink
 {
    internal class LocationConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            // registry information about what you are looking for. 
            // here i am looking to see where 7-Zip is installed
            string keyPath = $"SOFTWARE\\7-Zip";
            string valueName = "Path";
            string location = string.Empty;
            try
            {
                using (RegistryKey key = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64).OpenSubKey(keyPath))
                {
                     if (key != null)
                     {
                        object val = key.GetValue(valueName);

                        if (val != null && val is string)
                        {
                            location = (string)val;
                        }
                    }
                }
             }
             catch (Exception ex)
             {
                 Console.WriteLine($"Error accessing registry:{ex.Message}");
                 return string.Empty;
             }

             // here i am appending the static path to whatever you need. 
             // in this case its a file in the Lang directory. 
             return Path.Combine(location, "Lang", "af.txt");
         }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

You use the converter as a resource and bind it to the uri.

```
    <Window
    x:Class="ApplicationHyperLink.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ApplicationHyperLink"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    Title="MainWindow"
    Width="800"
    Height="450"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:LocationConverter x:Key="LocationConverter" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Hyperlink NavigateUri="{Binding Converter={StaticResource LocationConverter}}" RequestNavigate="Hyperlink_RequestNavigate">
            Link
        </Hyperlink>
    </TextBlock>
</Window>
```

you can bind a value to the uri and still use a converter. in that case the bound value will be passed in as the value parameter on the convert function. On top of that, you can pass in a value for parameter. If you wanted to get fancy and make the converter reusable you can bind the application and use the static path as the parameter.

Comment: I have managed to make this work. Deleted the unnecessary comments about errors. I had put extra backslashes in where they were not needed through my own silliness :)